# C# predictive coding for image compression

Tags: c#, image-processing, encoding

I've been playing with Huffman Compression on images to reduce size while maintaining a lossless image, but I've also read that you can use predictive coding to further compress image data by reducing entropy.

From what I understand, in the lossless JPEG standard, each pixel is predicted as the weighted average of the adjacent 4 pixels already encountered in raster order (three above and one to the left). e.g., trying to predict the value of a pixel a based on preceding pixels, x, to the left as well as above a :

```
x x x
x a
```

Then calculate and encode the residual (difference between predicted and actual value).

But what I don't get is if the average 4 neighbor pixels aren't a multiple of 4, you'd get a fraction right?  Should that fraction be ignored?  If so, would the proper encoding of an 8 bit image (saved in a `byte[]`) be something like:

```
public static void Encode(byte[] buffer, int width, int height)
{
    var tempBuff = new byte[buffer.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        tempBuff[i] = buffer[i];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
        {
            int offsetUp = ((i - 1) * width) + (j - 1);
            int offset = (i * width) + (j - 1);

            int a = tempBuff[offsetUp];
            int b = tempBuff[offsetUp + 1];
            int c = tempBuff[offsetUp + 2];
            int d = tempBuff[offset];
            int pixel = tempBuff[offset + 1];

            var ave = (a + b + c + d) / 4;
            var val = (byte)(ave - pixel);
            buffer[offset + 1] = val;
        }
    }
}

public static void Decode(byte[] buffer, int width, int height)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < width - 1; j++)
        {
            int offsetUp = ((i - 1) * width) + (j - 1);
            int offset = (i * width) + (j - 1);

            int a = buffer[offsetUp];
            int b = buffer[offsetUp + 1];
            int c = buffer[offsetUp + 2];
            int d = buffer[offset];
            int pixel = buffer[offset + 1];

            var ave = (a + b + c + d) / 4;
            var val = (byte)(ave - pixel);
            buffer[offset + 1] = val;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see how this really will reduce entropy?  How will this help compress my images further while still being lossless?

Thanks for any enlightenment

EDIT:

So after playing with the predictive coding  images, I noticed that the histogram data shows a lot of +-1's of the varous pixels.  This reduces entropy quite a bit in some cases.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just truncate.  Doesn't matter because you store the difference.  It reduces entropy because you only store small values, a lot of them will be -1, 0 or 1.  There are a couple of off-by-one bugs in your snippet btw.

Comment: Really?   could you point out which parts are off-by-one?  That would be excellent :)  Also, talking about -1 values, how would I handle the negative values?  Just have them loop around to 255?

Comment: Okay, I see it now, you're avoiding the border.  Yes, let the overflow.

Comment: Ok, I did a quick comparison of the Histograms and I see what you are saying!  I'll post a picture of what it looks like.  Thanks for you explaination!